# How to select out equivalent but inverted tuples in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have a table with 2 columns, filled with numeric values:

```
Column1     Column2
  1             2
  6             9
  2             1
  9             6
  1             3
```

Tuple (x,y) is equivalent to tuple (y,x) in the domain of my problem, and i need to perform a select where i get only one of them. Meaning, i would like a select query that returns:

```
Column1   Column2
  1          2
  6          9
  1          3
```

Which is the best approach to accomplish this in mySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t.*
from table t
where column1 < column2 or
      not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.column1 = t.column2 and t1.column2 = t.column1
                 );
```

If you just want pairs, even if they are not in the original table, then you can do:

```
select least(column1, column2), greatest(column1, column2)
from table t
group by least(column1, column2), greatest(column1, column2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This One, This query more quickly

```
Select  Distinct 
        Case When Column1 >= Column2 Then Column2 else Column1 End as a,
        Case When Column1 >= Column2 Then Column1 else Column2 End as b
From #table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 2 values you can group by the sum and use `min` and `max` to select each value.

```
select min(Column1), max(Column2)
from Table1
group by (Column1+Column2)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b856e/1